# How do I read all the images with a specific prefix in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, face-recognition

I am building a Face Recognition system. All the detected faces are stored in a directory. (Its stores both known and unknown)

I want to create a log of all the unknown faces. The unknown faces are stored with a prefix unknown_2203.png

My Question how do I fetch the unknown.pngs from that directory and show them on a django template?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only the images who has the prefix 'unknown' this will workout for you

```
x=unknown_12.png
Split x where an underscore occurs
a,b=x.split('_')
```

Looping through all the images and finding which image has a prefix 'unknown' in it's name can be done this way

```
x=['known_1.png','unknown_1.png','known_2.png']
for i in x:
    a,b=i.split('_')
    if a=='unknown':
        print(i)
```

Output :

```
unknown_1.png
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you also help me figure out how do I show all the files on a django template?

Comment: Look up jinja tutorials.